# How to group of Lists of Lists of Objects based on the first element of the list

Tags: scala

How to group of Lists of `Lists` of `Objects` based on the first element of the list?

One of the libraries I am using returns me a list of lists of objects.

```
val result = (List(PersonObj(name=John,Id=23), LikesOrder(type=toys, order=1), ItemLiked(type=figurerine,id=23)), 
List( PersonObj(name=John,Id=23), LikesOrder(type=toys, order=2), ItemLiked(type=figurerine,id=32))
),List( PersonObj(name=Tiffanny,Id=32), LikesOrder(type=toys, order=1), ItemLiked(type=figurerine,id=23) ))
```

Each item on the list represents 1 user interaction. On the list that I have provided we have 3 entries of interaction. Where 2 of those entries are from John which has an id of 23, and has 2 item liked.

Is there a way for me to achieve this?

the result of the above will result into map of `Map<PersonObj, List<ItemLiked>>`?

Is this possible with Scala?

Comment: What’s wrong with groupBy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy and asInstanceOf, though this is slightly unsafe (it could throw):

```
@ result.groupBy(_(0).asInstanceOf[PersonObj])
res11: Map[PersonObj, List[List[Product with Serializable with Object]]] = Map(
  PersonObj("Tiffanny", 32) -> List(List(PersonObj("Tiffanny", 32), LikesOrder("toys", 1), ItemLiked("figurerine", 23))),
  PersonObj("John", 23) -> List(
    List(PersonObj("John", 23), LikesOrder("toys", 1), ItemLiked("figurerine", 23)),
    List(PersonObj("John", 23), LikesOrder("toys", 2), ItemLiked("figurerine", 32))
  )
)
```

Then you can flatten the values so that you're left with the summed list for each PersonObj:

```
@ result.groupBy(_(0).asInstanceOf[PersonObj]).mapValues(_.flatten)
res12: Map[PersonObj, List[Product with Serializable with Object]] = Map(
  PersonObj("Tiffanny", 32) -> List(PersonObj("Tiffanny", 32), LikesOrder("toys", 1), ItemLiked("figurerine", 23)),
  PersonObj("John", 23) -> List(
    PersonObj("John", 23),
    LikesOrder("toys", 1),
    ItemLiked("figurerine", 23),
    PersonObj("John", 23),
    LikesOrder("toys", 2),
    ItemLiked("figurerine", 32)
  )
)
```

Finally you can filter out only the ItemLiked:

```
@ result.groupBy(_(0).asInstanceOf[PersonObj]).mapValues(_.flatten.filter(_.isInstanceOf[ItemLiked]))
res13: Map[PersonObj, List[Product with Serializable with Object]] = Map(
  PersonObj("Tiffanny", 32) -> List(ItemLiked("figurerine", 23)),
  PersonObj("John", 23) -> List(ItemLiked("figurerine", 23), ItemLiked("figurerine", 32))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the inner list is always `PersonObj`,`LikesOrder`, `ItemLiked` you can

```
case class PersonObj(name: String, Id: Int)
case class LikesOrder(ttype: String, order: Int)
case class ItemLiked(ttype: String, id: Int)



val result = List(
  List(PersonObj(name="John",Id=23),
    LikesOrder(ttype="toys", order=1),
    ItemLiked(ttype="figurerine",id=23)),
  List( PersonObj(name="John",Id=23),
    LikesOrder(ttype="toys", order=2),
    ItemLiked(ttype="figurerine",id=32)),
  List( PersonObj(name="Tiffanny",Id=32),
    LikesOrder(ttype="toys", order=1),
    ItemLiked(ttype="figurerine",id=23) ))

val r1 =result.map(l => {
  val List(p:PersonObj,_: LikesOrder,il : ItemLiked) = l
  (p -> il)
})

r1.groupBy{case (p,_)=>p}.map{case (p,l) => (p,l.map(_._2))}
```